# Conditional Formatting with Date less than 30 days

Tags: conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a conditional format where if cell F3 has a date that is less than 30 days from Today, the color in cell D3 changes. I've tried everything I can think of and nothing is working. HELP!

Comment: Excel, Google Sheets,,, which spreadsheet software?

Comment: Microsoft Excel

Answer (score 0):

1. On the Home tab of the ribbon, select Conditional Formatting > New Rule
2. Select 'Format only cells that contain'
3. Leave the first drop-down set to 'Cell Value'.
4. Select 'less than' from the second drop down.
5. Enter =TODAY()-30 in the box next to it.
6. Click Format...
7. Activate the Fill tab and select a color.
8. Click OK